# Product of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we have two rational varieties (i.e varieties which are birational to some projective space) is their product also a rational variety? would this rely on the fact that the Zariski topology is finer than the product topology and that $\mathbb{P}^{r} \times \mathbb{P}^{s}$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^{r+s}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you write is correct but it's even simpler than that: projective space needn't be invoked, nor the product topology.

To say that $X$ (resp. $X'$) is a rational variety means that some non-empty open subset $U\subset X$ (resp. $U'\subset X'$) is isomorphic to some open  subset $V\subset \mathbb A^n$ (resp. $V'\subset \mathbb A^{n'}$).
But then the open subset $U\times U'\subset X\times X'$  is isomorphic to the open subset $V\times V'\subset \mathbb A^{n}\times \mathbb A^{n'}=\mathbb A^{n+n'}$, proving that $X\times X'$ is rational.

Comment: thanks, I've noticed you know a lot about algebraic geometry. I'm a beginner and I would like to learn about schemes, sheaves, etc. What book(s) do you recommend for self study? (I find Hartshorne kinda hard sometimes)

Comment: Dear user 10, Hartshorne is *very* hard. It contains an impressive lot of material but it is best used as a reference book.Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry* (in two volumes) is the only book that develops classical varieties, schemes and holomorphic complex manifolds. The pace is leisurely and  there is an astonishing wealth of classical examples in the text.The style  is a little old-fashioned, though: proofs are sometimes a bit long-winded because commutative algebra is very little used. The historical remarks are very interesting and  the covers are aesthetically very pleasing, too!

Comment: The book is at the other extreme from Bourbaki : there are no long chains of logical dependence and the second volume  can be seen as a set of complementary chapters that you can dip into according to your taste.